# Elixir: How to invert a map (swap keys and values)?

Tags: elixir

I have a map like this:

```
%{
  "US" => "United States",
  "CA" => "Canada",
  "NL" => "The Netherlands"
}
```

I'd like to swap the keys with the values, resulting in a map like this:

```
%{
  "United States" => "US",
  "Canada" => "CA",
  "The Netherlands" => "NL"
}
```

What's the best way to do "invert" or "reverse" a map like this? I don't see a dedicated function for it anywhere.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One easy way is to use `Map.new`. It takes a function where you can specify the new key & value for each pair:

```
Map.new(map, fn {key, val} -> {val, key} end)
```

Answer (score 8):

More approaches:

1. [`Enum.into/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#into/3):

   ```
   Enum.into(map, %{}, &{elem(&1, 1), elem(&1, 0)})
   ```
2. [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#for/1) comprehension:

   ```
   for {k, v} <- map, into: %{}, do: {v, k}
   ```